# Python PyQt6 QWidgetAction, QFrame not showing in QPushButton menu

Tags: python, pyqt6

I am trying to place a horizontal `QFrame` in a `Qmenu` attached to a `QPushbutton`, but it won't show.  Calling actions() on the `QMenu` (in the MRE) returns 6 actions, yet the frames don't show up.  Is this because frames can't be added to a menu?  Here is the Meal Ready to Eat:

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets as W


class GUI(W.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button = W.QPushButton('TEST')
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        menu = W.QMenu()
        button.setMenu(menu)
        for e in range(3):
            label = W.QLabel(f'Placeholder {e}')
            widget = W.QWidgetAction(menu)
            widget.setDefaultWidget(label)
            menu.addAction(widget)
            frame = W.QFrame()
            frame.setFrameShape(W.QFrame.Shape.HLine)
            widget = W.QWidgetAction(menu)
            widget.setDefaultWidget(frame)
            menu.addAction(widget)


app = W.QApplication([])
main_gui = GUI()
main_gui.show()
app.exec()
```

I've tried setting a frame width, but still nothing shows.  Above is the MRE that should, at the least, be spaced for a frame.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just [`addSeparator()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmenu.html#addSeparator)?

Comment: In my project, that's what I've done.  But, separators, being actions, cannot be styled.  So, I want a frame (and `QLables`) to open up styling (via `setStyleSheet`, etc.).  Font's, colors, etc.  My app will have a configurable theme, so my menus, etc. need to change colors, etc.

Comment: QMenu [supports customization through style sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qmenu), unless you want a *per-item* customization (something I would strongly discourage, as it's terrible from the UX perspective). Consider that using custom widgets instead of normal actions is generally a bad idea, because they do not easily provide keyboard navigation, proper focus and mouse event handling, and shortcut management. You either implement **all that** on your own, or many of your users will have "fancy" menus that lack the basic conventions of standard UI menus.

Comment: Food for thought.  Thanks, @musicamante.  My basic thing was just "fanciness".  I may drop back to a conventional menu/action system.  Fewer lines of code to scour through.  But, for app theming, the menu can be changed (which I knew and implemented), but the text cannot.  Which means black text, light background.  Or, can text be customized?  I think so.  But, it's all good.  I may drop back, it is simpler.  I'm a hobbyist; not getting paid here.

Comment: You squared me away (*yet again*), @musicamante.  I can do all I want with a `QMenu` stylesheet that I was trying to do the hard way.  The only thing I haven't figured yet is font.  Maybe you can work with it, maybe you can't.

Comment: `app.setStyleSheet('QMenu { font-family: SomeCustomFont; font-size: 18pt; }')`. Please take your time to carefully read the *whole* official stylesheet documentation, and take extra consideration on the examples: before trying to achieve everything you need to do from scratch, start with the given examples, and change some properties to see the effect, in order to better understand how they work. Unfortunately, the QSS documentation has not really improved in the last 2 major versions of Qt, and some aspects of complex widgets are a bit obscure, unclear, or poorly explained.

Comment: Also note that if you need to use custom font that may not be included in the target computers, you must use [QFontDatabase](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfontdatabase.html).

Comment: My fault, @musicamante.  I didn't explain well/was misleading in wording.  I'm not tacking fonts yet.  Things are at system default for now.  What I want to do is partial string weighting and italicizing.  I don't think that can be done via stylesheets.  *Partial* string editing.  That's why I went with the hard way to begin with.  It's all good--just fluff and puff.